# Using --prefer-dist with Composer will result in not found, The source however can be found

Tags: php, github, ssh, composer-php

I am figuring out how to use Composer for my own projects dependencies. I have some **private** GitHub repo's that I need to include in my project.

Lets say we have

- A - Main project
- B - Dependency
- C - Dependency2

Now this is the JSON in A:

```
{
  "name": "vendor/package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "require": {
    "vendor/package" : "1.0.0",
    "vendor/package2" : "1.0.0"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:vendor/package.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:vendor/package2.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the package for B (C is very similar ofcourse)

```
{
  "name": "vendor/package1",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Now if I run the following command:

```
composer install -n --prefer-dist
```

The following error occurs:

```
  - Installing vendor/package (1.0.0)
    Downloading: Failed       
    Failed to download vendor/package from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/vendor/package/zipball/419f5056bde4ff7d76a099648e60fc" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing vendor/package (1.0.0)
    Cloning 419f5056bde4ff7d48e60fc
```

Downloading the source however does work. I have installed SSH keys in my ~/.ssh folder and on Github. This seems to work as the source can be downloaded. I am however surprised that I can't get the zip package. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Greets,

Comment: Private repository issues are incredibly hard to debug for us Composer maintainers as we simply cannot see what is going wrong.

I do not have any private repositories myself either, so I cannot replicate your situation.

Can you try running in the most verbose state (`-vvv`) and see if you get any more meaningful output?

Comment: downloading https://api.github.com/repos/vendor/package/zipball/4e294157a40f12f59b9e8d3ef011be878fe89ea439
    Downloading: Failed

Failed: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 404: The"https://api.github.com/repos/vendor/package/zipball/4e294157a40f" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Failed to download vendor/package from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/vendor/package/zipball/4e294157a40f12f57889ea439" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    download source
  - Installing vendor/package (1.0.0)

Comment: This is really all I got.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason API calls seem to be failing. You can try disabling this by modifying your repository definitions:

```
{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "git@github.com:vendor/package.git",
  "no-api": true
}
```

**Alternatively:**

It *could be* that for private repositories you would need a valid oauth token configured, but for some reason it does not seem to prompt for this in the current/latest version of Composer.

To configure an oauth token, create one @ [github.com/settings/tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens), and then add it to your config like so:

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>
```

Please let me know which of these methods solves it for you.